# Angular 15.1 - Infinite Loop on Change Detection when removing babel-polyfill

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection, babel-polyfill, angular-devkit

We had a an old babel-polyfill in our project. Now, when we remove it, Angular DevTools shows an infinite Change Detetction Loop with Source "Window.addEventListener:message".

Anyone has an idea, whats wrong ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you provide a stackblitz repro ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
Core-js is a dependency of babel-polyfill and was removed with babel-polyfill. Now, if i add core-js, it works again. But i dont know why, i need it, so if anybody knows the answer, please let me know :)